Spring Batch - could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
I am facing some issues with Spring Batch metadata tables upon transactions.

org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
    VALUES(?, ?, ?)
]; ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
  Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during conflict in checking.
  Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:115)

caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
  Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during conflict in checking.
  Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2725)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)

I have even add the below in the configuration as well

ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED

I need some help here.

It seems that ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED is still aggressive. Have you tried to lower it to ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED ? This should not be necessary, but it seems that you are launching a lot of batch jobs simultaneously. Is that the case? What is the frequency of job launching?

@MahmoudBenHassine thanks for you reply.  Yes 50+ jobs have to be run as per requirement.  Could you help me with this? how to handle this?

Try to lower the isolation level to ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED and see. Otherwise lower it more. Spring Batch can do nothing for this.

as per comments I have used the is ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED and it works now without any issues.

Good to hear you solved your issue!

At what level and where are you using ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED.
